# Eureka Client Registration Failed in Docker compose: Failing to register as client - but eureka server & client is individually up & running

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, netflix-eureka

I have a spring boot application for **Eureka Server**:

**application.yml (Eureka Server)**

```
server:
  port: 8761

spring:
  application:
    name: eureka

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
```

I have a eureka client - say microservice2

**application.yml (Eureka Client - microservice2)**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: second-feign-client

server:
  port: 8082

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

**Dockerfile: (same for both eureka-server app & microservice2 app)**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

locally, Eureka client, **microservice2**, registering with Eureka Server perfectly. Both are spring boot applications. I have dockerized both applications, & pushed to docker hub. I am trying to run these two applications in docker-compose, but the eureka client is failing to register in eureka server using docker-compose.

I am getting this error:

```
microservice2_1  | 2020-09-07 13:56:36.149 ERROR 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : D
iscoveryClient_SECOND-FEIGN-CLIENT/379b7c698e87:second-feign-client:8082 - was unable to refresh its cache! status =
Cannot execute request on any known server
microservice2_1  |
microservice2_1  | com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known ser
ver
microservice2_1  |      at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(Retryab
leEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-1.9.25.jar!/:1.9.25]
microservice2_1  |      at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications
(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.25.jar!/:1.9.25]
microservice2_1  |      at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(Eurek
aHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.25.jar!/:1.9.25]
microservice2_1  |      at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(Session
edEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.25.jar!/:1.9.25]
microservice2_1  |      at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications
(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.25.jar!/:1.9.25]
microservice2_1  |      at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1097) [
eureka-client-1.9.25.jar!/:1.9.25]
microservice2_1  |      at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1011) [eureka-cli
ent-1.9.25.jar!/:1.9.25]
microservice2_1  |      at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1533) [eureka-c
lient-1.9.25.jar!/:1.9.25]
microservice2_1  |      at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1500) [e
ureka-client-1.9.25.jar!/:1.9.25]
microservice2_1  |      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_212]
microservice2_1  |      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_212]
microservice2_1  |      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_
212]
microservice2_1  |      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_
212]
microservice2_1  |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
microservice2_1  |
eureka-server_1  | 2020-09-07 13:56:39.393  INFO 1 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : R
unning the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
```

**I have gone through already discussed related question** [docker-eureka-spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667063/docker-and-eureka-with-spring-boot-failing-to-register-clients) **I have tried all these discussed options, but still not working.**

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  eureka-server:
    image: dineshdontha67/eureka-server:latest
    ports:
    - "8761:8761"
    networks:
      - ms-network
  microservice2:
    image: dineshdontha67/microservice2:latest
    ports:
    - "8082:8082"
    networks:
      - ms-network
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
    environment:
      server.port: 8082
      eureka.instance.hostname: localhost
      eureka.client.enabled: 'true'

#EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE: http://localhost:8761/eureka
#    networks:
#      - ms-network
#    depends_on:
#      - eureka-server
#      server.port: 8082
#      eureka.host: eureka-server
#      eureka.client.enabled: 'true'
#      eureka.instance.preferIpAddress: 'true'

networks:
  ms-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Note: After docker-compose up, both the spring boot applications are running fine individually, but only registration is failing.

```
E:\eureka-server>docker-compose ps
            Name                     Command         State           Ports
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
eureka-server_eureka-server_1   java -jar /app.jar   Up      0.0.0.0:8761->8761/tcp
eureka-server_microservice2_1   java -jar /app.jar   Up      0.0.0.0:8082->8082/tcp
```

**Reference Repos:**

microservices2 git repo (acts as eureka-client) : [microservices2](https://github.com/donthadineshkumar/spring-boot-microservice2.git)

eureka-server git repo(acts as eureka server): [eureka-server](https://github.com/donthadineshkumar/spring-boot-eureka-server.git)

Please help me on this. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

```yml
version: "3.8"
services:
  eureka-server:
    image: dineshdontha67/eureka-server:latest
    ports:
    - "8761:8761"
    networks:
      - ms-network
   environment:
      eureka.instance.hostname: eureka-server
      eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka/

  microservice2:
    image: dineshdontha67/microservice2:latest
    ports:
    - "8082:8082"
    networks:
      - ms-network
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
    environment:
      server.port: 8082
      eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka/

#EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE: http://localhost:8761/eureka
#    networks:
#      - ms-network
#    depends_on:
#      - eureka-server
#      server.port: 8082
#      eureka.host: eureka-server
#      eureka.client.enabled: 'true'
#      eureka.instance.preferIpAddress: 'true'

networks:
  ms-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Override hostname according to your service name

cheers

Comment: How do you create network aka-network in the same file? or using `docker network aka-network`

Comment: No luck. But, I have added my repos, `docker-compose.yml` is in eureka-server repo (included in root path), you just go over once

Comment: I did not try but it I think you forgot to expose the port in the dockerfile. Try EXPOSE 8761 for eureka and EXPOSE 8082 for the other one

Answer (score 0):

```
version: "3.8"

networks:  
  ms-network:  
    name: ms-network  
    driver: bridge

services:
  eureka-server:
    image: dineshdontha67/eureka-server:latest
    ports:
    - "8761:8761"
    networks:
      - ms-network
    environment:
      eureka.instance.hostname: eureka-server
      eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka

  microservice2:
    image: dineshdontha67/book-service:latest
    ports:
    - "8082:8080"
    networks:
      - ms-network
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
    environment:
      server.port: 8082
      eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
```

Comment: I just tried with above one its working for me

Comment: eureka-server application packaging type JAR, and microservice2 packaging type war.